# How to print Image gallery descriptions

Tags: php, label

I have a image gallery with 15 pics, it shows the first image in normal size and the rest are thumbs on the bottom, when you click the thumbs it replaces the normal size image with that one, and if you click the normal sized image it shows on a lightbox style popup with the image description.
This gallery layout is called Galleria and its part of the SIG Pro joomla plugin:

http://demo.joomlaworks.net/simple-image-gallery-pro

The image descriptions for each image are shown on the popup, but I would like to remove this behavior and show the description below the normal sized image.
My question is regarding PHP, I'm very noob at this. 
For what I figured out I can print all the thumbs descriptions with this:

```
<?php foreach($gallery as $count=>$photo): ?>
<p class="sigProGalleriaTargetTxt"><?php echo $photo->captionDescription; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But what I want to print is only the description of the image that is selected. 
I tried this:

```
<p class="sigProGalleriaTargetTxt"><?php echo $gallery[0]->captionDescription; ?></p>
```

But this only prints the first image description, because it has the value 0 (first image).
I see that I need to increment the value of $gallery according to the selected image.
How can I achieve this?

Here is the complete php file:
http://codepad.org/MlPbgPzl

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

What about using som javascript/dom to set the captions? its a bit of a hacky but, i would try to have an onClick Event which calls a function to apply the description.

in the thumbs sections something like:

```
<span class="sigProLinkWrapper">
    <a onClick="setDesc('<?php echo $photo->captionDescription; ?>');" href="...
```

and for the description:

```
// leaving the <?php tag like this, so you get always the first description
// but adding an id tag
<p id='photoDescription' class="sigProGalleriaTargetTxt">$gallery[0]->captionDescription; ?></p>
```

and finally replacing it with some javascript (or jquery if youre using that)

```
function setDesc(photoDesc)
{
    var descContainer = document.getElementById("photoDescription").innerHTML= photoDesc;
}
```

maybe it helps :)